# What are DXImageTransform and DXImageTransform.Microsoft?

Tags: html, css

What are `DXImageTransform` and `DXImageTransform.Microsoft`? When should we use them? What are its uses?

I have tried googling, but it only returns basic examples. I want to know when should we use these two things, and what will they do? I added `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader` to one of my images, but nothing happened.

Comment: Here is a good link that will help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532849(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are *proprietary Microsoft methods and properties*, notice the menu says *Legacy APIs*.

Even if it was 2010 it still wouldn't be worth learning any of those unless you have a blindly enthusiastic IE8-using boss who wants some of the more current effects on their website and is willing to pay you a lot for it.

If you want to understand some (not all) though a very good sized selection of cutting-edge goodies including CSS I recommend you start at caniuse...

http://caniuse.com/